# Android check if phone has mobile or wireless connection issue

Tags: android, wireless

I have the following method to check if my device has either mobile or wifi connection:

```
public static boolean haveNetworkConnection(ConnectivityManager cm) {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

The code seems to work fine (returns true), when the phone is connected to wifi, however when the phone is not connected the method still returns true.

I have tested to make sure that the phone is totally disconnected as none of my other apps can connect to the Internet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the `ConnectivityManager` like so:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

Read more about it at http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean checkInternetConnection(Activity _activity) {
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) _activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&  conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

The above method retrun true if you have any available/connected network